# Redirect with message after admin_post.php

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin

I've searched the web and this site, however i can't find my answer.

I have a plugin, wich has a sub-menu page. On this page, there is a form that post's the information to `admin-post.php`, and that gets handled by a action.

After i finish processing the post, i want to redirect the user back, however i want to include a message, as wordpress natively does, telling if there were any errors or if it was successfull.

[image: Page updated redirect message example]

I've read about `wp_redirect` with `add_query_arg` but i can't make it work.

I've also read [this post (Show Admin Message on Redirect)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/242399/show-admin-message-on-redirect/242495#242495) but i think this does not fit my necessity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the [`admin_notices` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_notices/).

Comment: From what I've seen, this way it will not clear itself after has been shown 1 time.